# Subtract a number from an ASCII char

Tags: c++, ascii

[Converting lower & upper case ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599230/converting-lower-upper-case-ascii-characters-c)

So, I'm trying to do what is in that thread, except I want to go backwards for ascii conversion (letters only) aka, if I gave the number 1.

```
b+1 = a

B+1 = A (capital becomes capital)

c+2 = a

z+1 = y

a+1 = z
```

```
int lower_add = ((letter - 'a' - input_int) % 26) +'a';
if ((lower_add -'a' - input_int) < 0)
    lower_add = lower_add +26;
```

This is almost getting it, except there are some cases where b+1 will go to some other non-letter ascii char.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting lower & upper case ascii characters C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599230/converting-lower-upper-case-ascii-characters-c)

Comment: That is exactly the same as what you’ve asked before. How is that question not already answered?

Comment: In your examples, it seems like `+` really means `-`.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3):

`lower_add` already has `input_int` subtracted out, don't do it a second time.  Change your `if` to:

```
if (lower_add < 'a')
    lower_add += 26;
```

This still won't deal with capital letters correctly, you'll probably need a range test to decide whether to subtract `'a'` or `'A'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

class letter { 
    char current;
public:
    letter(char x) : current(x) {}
    letter &operator+=(int v) { 
        if (islower(current)) {
            int pos = current - 'a' - v;
            if (pos < 0) pos += 26;
            current = pos + 'a';
        }
        else if (isupper(current)) {
            int pos = current - 'A' - v;
            if (pos < 0) pos += 26; 
            current = pos + 'A';
        }
        return *this;
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, letter const &l) { 
        return os << l.current;
    }   
};

int main() { 
    letter a('c');
    a += 3;
    std::cout << a;
}
```